# get computed or default style of button and set on a new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where i have define Custom html elements and give them a style.
I am trying to create a button with default style and take computed style of button and set it to another custom element, with button active and hover effects.

but its not work for me.. is any buddy have solution or idea ?

here my code :

```
var A_btnfake = document.createElement('button'); 
cS = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(A_btnfake, null);
A_btn = document.createElement('custbtn');
A_btn.style=cS;
some_elm.appendChild(A_btn);
//i don't want to define each style one by one,like :  A_btn.style.background = cS.backGround
```

Is there any way to define all style at once .

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly you want to define the styles all at once? This can be done through CSS directly, there is no need to do it through javascript/jQuery


If you're looking for something to start with I would recommend looking [here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/four-simple-and-fun-css-button-hover-effects-for-beginners/)

Comment: Yeh,, but i want default style of button,like in IE ! with there hover and active effects.

Comment: Those effects are not created by CSS, they are a part of the native behavior of the `HTMLButtonElement`.

Comment: So is there any trick to take that native behavior ? @Teemu

Comment: I am not aware of any trick like that, though it doesn't mean there wouldn't be a one.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> A_btn.style=cS;
> ```

The [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) is *read-only* - you cannot assign a completely new `CSSStyleDeclaration` object to an element, only get its (probably element-tied) one.

If you want to copy a style to another, you will have to do it property-by-property:

```
for (var prop in cS)
    A_btn.style[prop] = cS[prop];
```

Comment: You also need to add the fake element to the DOM or the computed styles returns nothing.

Comment: This seems to work in IE only, Chrome and FF display `style=""`.

Comment: Works but partially !!  @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this via CSS, especially if you want to inherit the `:active` and `:hover` states. And it’s really easy, just add the new element to the selector list, f.ex:

```
button,
custbtn { color: yellow; }
```

Note that in some older versions of IE, you need to virtually add new custom elements in order to be able to target them via CSS (same goes for HTML5 elements).